# Do you need to disclose that you are sending error logs from their organization to a server you own and disclose security risks associated with it?

Tags: united-states, privacy

Do you need to disclose that you are sending error logs from their organization to a server you own and disclose security risks associated with it?

We have an application hosted on our own AWS servers for each organization and we're sending error logs to our own server, to which we have access, which means we may send some private data owned by them to our own server. Do we need to disclose that to our partners? Assume the company is in the U.S. I heard it's ok since we're not using that data in any shape or form.

Comment: Whether or not it's "ok", they may be unhappy if they find out it's happening. Which probably should make you figure out how to not make it be a surprise for them at any point... which is probably best achieved by talking about it immediately.

Comment: Much better than disclosing things is to change your logging code so that no private information is sent to your server. And how do you know that nobody in your company looks at this private data? If you have private data you have to protect it against unauthorised access.